# Windows 10: Restore hidden application windows

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar, restore, task-manager

Every once in a while, I mistakenly Hold Alt and Shift while typing 2 or 3 or 4 (but not 1). When that happens, then one of the applications I have open disappears. Note that this doesn't mean its window is minimised or behind other applications. Rather, it disappears from the task bar and from Alt+Tab and Windows+Tab listings, but still appears in Task Manager. And if it has an icon in the system tray, then that icon stays there too.

I have suspected that I'm moving applications to a different desktop of some sort (desktop 2 or 3 or 4, me currently being on number 1), but I have only one desktop.

How do I bring my application windows back?

Comment: There is a little up arrow  ^  on the right hand side of the taskbar (Hidden Icons).  Has the program gone there?

Comment: Alt-shift-2 , 3 or 4 does not have any effect on my system. It could still be that this is from a Virtual Desktop manager, but not the one that natively comes with Windows.

Comment: @John No, then I'd be able to switch to it with Alt+Tab too. However, I've now found out what it was. Entirely my own fault.

Comment: @LPChip Indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is my own fault. I was running Dexpot, but only for its ability to pin windows. Since I never used its virtual desktop functionality, I never thought of it as such.